# tsconfig.json - extends - compiler not using other tsconfig.json files

Tags: json, typescript

I'm trying to split out my tsconfig.json into separate files. One for the src files, and one for the tests. When I split them out, and used the extends field, it doesn't seem to work. Only the base tsconfig.json is used. What am I doing wrong?

```
{ // tsconfig.json
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "lib": [
            "es2017"
        ],
        "module": "commonjs",
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "target": "es6",
        "types": [
            "jest",
            "node",
            "express",
            "electron",
            "cors"
        ],
        "noUnusedLocals": true
    }
}

{ // tsconfig.src.json
    "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "main"
    },
    "include": [
        "src"
    ]
}

{ // tsconfig.src.json
    "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "out-tests"
    },
    "include": [
        "src-tests"
    ]
}
```

Comment: What doesn't "doesn't seem to work" mean? What's the difference between the observed behavior and the expected behavior?

Comment: The compiler seems to ignore the other tsconfig.json files. I expect to get a folder called "main" with all the compiled js from src, and a folder called "out-tests" with all the compiled js test from src-tests. But when I run "tsc" in cmd, I get all the compiled js and js test in the src folder.

Answer (score 0):

tsc doesn't look for all tsconfig.*.json automatically by itself. If you want to compile with different tsconfig, you'll have to specify it by yourself using the -p parameter:

```
tsc -p tsconfig.src.json
tsc -p tsconfig.test.json
```

From tsc help:

> -p FILE OR DIRECTORY, --project FILE OR DIRECTORY  Compile the project given the path to its configuration file, or to a folder with a
> 'tsconfig.json'.